# Symfony 3.3 FOSRestBundle + FOSUserBundle + PUGXMultiuserBundle Registration with postman CSRF protection is invalid

Tags: fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, csrf-protection, symfony-3.3, pugxmultiuserbundle

i'm using symfony 3.3, i build my application with FOSUserbundle and PUGXMultiuserBundle and everything is ok. and now i'm trying to create my API REST with FOSRestBundle, i got a problem when i'm trying to register a new user with postman.

```
{
"code": 400,
"message": "Validation Failed",
"errors": {
    "errors": [
        "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
    ],
    "children": {
        "email": {},
        "username": {},
        "plainPassword": {
            "children": {
                "first": {},
                "second": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

i used this example to build my API REST and it is good but didn't work with PUGXMultiuserBundle
[enter link description here](https://github.com/codereviewvideos/fos-rest-and-user-bundle-integration)

and this is my class for registration a new user

```
<?php
namespace Taseera\EndpointBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * @RouteResource("registration", pluralize=false)
 */
 class RegistrationUserOneController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

/**
 * @Annotations\Post("/register-company")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    //$request = $this->getRequest();
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
    $form = $formFactory->createForm(array('csrf_protection' => false));
    $discriminator = $this->container->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
    $discriminator->setClass('Taseera\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne');
    $userManager = $this->container->get('pugx_user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);
    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
    if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);
        if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return $response;
        }
        return $form;
    }
    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
    if ($event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
    $userManager->updateUser($user);
    $response = new JsonResponse(
        [
            'msg' => $this->get('translator')->trans('registration.flash.user_created', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'token' => $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->create($user), // creates JWT
        ],
        Response::HTTP_CREATED,
        [
            'Location' => $this->generateUrl(
                'get_profile',
                [ 'user' => $user->getId() ],
                UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
            )
        ]
    );
    $dispatcher->dispatch(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED,
        new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response)
    );
    return $response;
}


}
```

i'm using also "lexikjwt-authentication-bundle", "jms/serializer-bundle", "nelmio/api-doc-bundle" and "nelmio/cors-bundle"

this is my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern: ^/admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: admin_login
            check_path: admin_login_check
           # check_path verification de l'autentification
            default_target_path:    /admin
        logout:
             path:           /admin/logout
             target:         /admin/login
        anonymous:    true
    company:
        pattern: ^/company(.*)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: company_login
            check_path: company_login_check
           # check_path verification de l'autentification
            default_target_path:    /company/profile
        logout:
            path:           /company/logout
            target:         /company/login
        anonymous:    true
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: taseerafrontend_homepage
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    api:
        pattern:   ^/endpoint
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt: ~

    healthcheck:
        pattern: ^/endpoint/ping$
        anonymous: true

    api_docs:
        pattern: ^/endpoint/doc
        anonymous: true

    api_register:
        pattern: ^/endpoint/register-company
        anonymous: true
        security: false

    api_password_reset:
        pattern: ^/endpoint/password/reset
        anonymous: true

    api_login:
        pattern:  ^/endpoint/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /endpoint/login
            require_previous_session: false
            username_parameter:       username
            password_parameter:       password
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        logout: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/endpoint/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/company/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/company/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/company/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/company/, role: ROLE_COMPANY }
```

and this is my config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed#https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: ar
    category_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/backend/img/category'
    user_one_company_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/backend/img/company'
    medias_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/backend/img/medias'

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: ~
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
             e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Taseera\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    service:
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
    change_password:
        form:
            type:                
   \UserBundle\Form\ChangePasswordFormType # or 'fos_user_change_password' on Symfony < 2.8
            name:               fos_user_company_change_password_form
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
    #profile:
     #   form:
      #      type:    Taseera\CompanyBundle\Form\ProfileFormType # or 'fos_user_profile' on Symfony < 2.8
        #    name:    fos_user_company_profile
        #    validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]

pugx_multi_user:
    users:
        user_one:
            entity:
                class: Taseera\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne
            registration:
                form:
                    type: Taseera\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationUserOneFormType
                    name: fos_user_registration_form
                    validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
                template: TaseeraUserBundle:Registration:user_one.form.html.twig
            profile:
                  form:
                      type: Taseera\UserBundle\Form\ProfileUserOneFormType
                      name: fos_user_company_profile
                      validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
        user_two:
            entity:
                class: Taseera\UserBundle\Entity\UserTwo
            registration:
                form:
                    type: Taseera\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationUserTwoFormType
                    #name: fos_user_registration_form
                    validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
                template: TaseeraUserBundle:Registration:user_two.form.html.twig
            profile:
                form:
                    type: Taseera\UserBundle\Form\ProfileUserTwoFormType

fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: false
            rss: false
        mime_types:
            json: ['application/json', 'application/x-json']
            jpg: ['image/jpeg']
            png: ['image/png']
    routing_loader:
        default_format:  json
        include_format:  false
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/endpoint', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
    exception:
        enabled: true

#JMS Serializer
jms_serializer: ~


# CSA Guzzle
csa_guzzle:
    profiler: "%kernel.debug%"


# Lexik JWT Bundle
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: "%jwt_private_key_path%"
    public_key_path:  "%jwt_public_key_path%"
    pass_phrase:      "%jwt_key_pass_phrase%"
    token_ttl:        "%jwt_token_ttl%"

# Nelmio CORS
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_origin:  ["%cors_allow_origin%"]
        allow_methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        allow_headers: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]
        max_age:       3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~


# Nelmio API Doc
nelmio_api_doc: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and it's worked for me

i must desactivate the csrf_protection in the RegistrationUserOneFormType related to my entity UserOne like this

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}
```